# Hashing same character multiple times

Tags: python, string, algorithm, hash, md5

I'm doing a programming challenge and I'm going crazy with one of the challenges. In the challenge, I need to compute the MD5 of a string. The string is given in the following form:

`n[c]`: Where `n` is a number and `c` is a character. For example: `b3[a2[c]]` => `baccaccacc`

Everything went ok until I was given the following string:

`1[2[3[4[5[6[7[8[9[10[11[12[13[a]]]]]]]]]]]]]`

This strings turns into a string with 6227020800 `a`'s. This string is more than 6GB, so it's nearly impossible to compute it in practical time. So, here is my question:

**Are there any properties of MD5 that I can use here?**

I know that there has to be a form to make it in short time, and I suspect it has to be related to the fact that all the string has is the same character repeated multiple times.

Comment: This will probably be to simple, reverse-lookup and find the first occuring `[`, replace the character after (`a`) with the number infront of `[` (`13`, so  `13*'a'`) then sore that string in a variable, look for the next `[` and take `mystoredstring*num` and so on..

Comment: @Torxed This question is not about generating the actual string from its compact representation (which would be the letter a 6227020800 time, as the OP already stated), but about efficiently computing the MD5 hash of such a large string.

Comment: I can calculate it in about 14 seconds of CPU time on my machine. How do you define "practical time"?

Comment: @Aya Damn, I need 22 seconds :-) `68df0fa...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have created a (recursive) function to produce the result as a single value.  Instead you should use a generator to produce the result as a stream of bytes.  These you can then feed byte by byte into your MD5 hash routine.  The size of the stream does not matter this way, it will just have an impact on the computation time, not on the memory used.

Here's an example using a single-pass parser:

```
import re, sys, md5

def p(s, pos, callBack):
  while pos < len(s):
    m = re.match(r'(d+)[', s[pos:])
    if m:  # repetition?
      number = m.group(1)
      for i in range(int(number)):
        endPos = p(s, pos+len(number)+1, callBack)
      pos = endPos
    elif s[pos] == ']':
      return pos + 1
    else:
      callBack(s[pos])
      pos += 1
  return pos + 1

digest = md5.new()
def feed(s):
  digest.update(s)
  sys.stdout.write(s)
  sys.stdout.flush()

end = p(sys.argv[1], 0, feed)
print
print "MD5:", digest.hexdigest()
print "finished parsing input at pos", end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the property I've been searching for. Thanks for your inestimable help

Answer (score 0):

All hash functions are designed to work with byte streams, so you should not first generate the whole string, and after that hash it - you should write generator, which produces chunks of string data, and feed it to MD5 context.
And, MD5 uses 64-byte (or char) buffer so it would be a good idea to feed 64-byte chunks of data to the context.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the good properties of hashes:

```
import hashlib
cruncher = hashlib.md5()
chunk = 'a' * 100
for i in xrange(100000):
    cruncher.update(chunk)
print cruncher.hexdigest()
```

Tweak the number of rounds (x = 10000) and the length of the chunk (y = 100) so that x * y = 13!. The point is that your are feeding the algorithm with chunks of your string (each one x characters long), one after the other, for y times.